Is this partial differential equation solvable?
I was trying to solve the following PDE:
$$\ln(x_2)\partial_1U+x_2U\partial_2U-U=0$$
with the initial condition $$U(t+1,e)=1$$
I managed to get to the following system:
$$\begin{cases} \dot{x}_1(s)=ln(x_2)\\\dot{x}_2(s)=Ux_2 \\\dot{U}(s)=p_1\ln(x_2)+p_2x_2U \\ \dot{p_1}(s)=p_1-p_2p_1x_2 \\ \dot{p_2}(s)=p_2-\frac{p_1}{x_2}-Up_2-p^2_2x_2 \end{cases} $$
where $x_1>0,\quad x_2>0$ and $p_1=\partial_{x_1}U$ and $p_2=\partial_{x_2}U$.
But, I am not able to solve this system of ODEs. Please help!

Hi, from the first equation, please precise what are initially in your problem (how they are defined) $x_2$, $U$, and what are the other function that appear after namely $x_1$, $p_1$, p_2$, where do those equations come from ?

$x_2>0, x_1>0$ and $p_1=\partial_{x_1}U$ and $p_2=\partial_{x_2}U$

Ok put it all in the question so it will be perectly clear with all parameter, functions, initial conditions to help you through this problem.

See my answer in : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4936865/unsolvable-characteristic-system-ode-as-a-part-of-pde-solution .

The characteristic ODEs are
$$\frac{dx_{1}}{\ln x_{2}} = \frac{dx_{2}}{x_{2} u} = \frac{du}{u}$$
The last equality implies
ln u
$$u - \ln x_{2} = C_{1}$$
The first and third ratios imply
\begin{align}
d x_{1} &= \frac{(u - C_{1}) du}{u} \\
\implies u - C_{1} \ln u - x_{1} &= C_{2} \\
\implies u - C_{1} + C_{1} - C_{1} \ln u - x_{1} &= C_{2} \\
\implies \ln x_{2} + (u - \ln x_{2}) (1 - \ln u) - x_{1} &= C_{2} \\
\end{align}
and hence
$$\ln x_{2} + (u - \ln x_{2})(1 - \ln u) - x_{1} = f(u - \ln x_{2})$$
for some arbitrary differentiable function $f$. You can check this satisfies the PDE by differentiation
\begin{align}
u_{x_{1}}(1 - \ln u) - (u - \ln x_{2}) u_{x_{1}} u^{-1} - 1 &= u_{x_{1}} f' \\
\implies u_{x_{1}} \left(1 - \ln u - (u - \ln x_{2}) u^{-1} - f' \right) &= 1 \\
\implies u_{x_{1}} &= \frac{1}{\left(1 - \ln u - (u - \ln x_{2}) u^{-1} - f' \right)} \\
x_{2}^{-1} + (u_{x_{2}} - x_{2}^{-1})(1 - \ln u) - (u - \ln x_{2}) u_{x_{2}} u^{-1} &= (u_{x_{2}} - x_{2}^{-1}) f' \\
\implies u_{x_{2}} \left(1 - \ln u - (u - \ln x_{2}) u^{-1} - f' \right) &= - x_{2}^{-1} (\ln u + f') \\
\implies u_{x_{2}} &= \frac{- x_{2}^{-1} (\ln u + f')}{\left(1 - \ln u - (u - \ln x_{2}) u^{-1} - f' \right)}
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
\implies \ln x_{2} u_{x_{1}} + x_{2} u u_{x_{2}} &= \frac{\ln x_{2} - u (\ln u + f')}{\left(1 - \ln u - (u - \ln x_{2}) u^{-1} - f' \right)} \\
&= \frac{u (\ln x_{2} - u (\ln u + f'))}{\left(u - u \ln u - (u - \ln x_{2}) - u f' \right)} \\
&= \frac{u (- u \ln u + \ln x_{2} - u f')}{\left(- u \ln u + \ln x_{2} - u f' \right)} \\
&= u
\end{align}
I leave the domain of convergence and initial condition to you (hint for initial condition; the solution to the PDE can also be written as $$u - \ln x_{2} = g(\ln x_{2} + (u - \ln x_{2})(1 - \ln u) - x_{1})$$ for some arbitrary differentiable function $g$, then note that evaluating both sides at $(x_{1}, x_{2}, u) = (t + 1, e, 1)$ makes the LHS vanish identically).

The fact that $\partial_tU(1+t,e)=0$ seems to imply that $U(x_1,x_2)$ does not depend on $x_1$, which leads us to try the ansatz $U(x_1,x_2)=f(x_2)$. Plugging it into the PDE
$$
\ln(x_2)\partial_1U+x_2U\partial_2U-U=0, \tag{1}
$$
we get
$$
(x_2f'(x_2)-1)f(x_2)=0 \implies f(x_2)=0\quad\text{or}\quad x_2f'(x_2)-1=0. \tag{2}
$$
The first alternative must be discarded, as it does not satisfy the condition $$
U(1+t,e)=f(e)=1. \tag{3}
$$
The second alternative, on the other hand, yields
$$
f'(x_2)=\frac{1}{x_2} \implies f(x_2)=\ln(x_2)+C, \tag{4}
$$
which satisfies $(3)$ if $C=0$. Therefore, a solution to $(1)$ (I make no claim that the solution is unique) is
$$
U(x_1,x_2)=\ln(x_2). \tag{5}
$$
